# C: How to add Ncurses and Math Flags into CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c, cmake, ncurses, math.h

I'm importing a C project into the Clion IDE, that uses Cmake.
My project uses these external libraries: Math and Ncurses.
However i'm not able to get the script CMakeLists.txt working.

This is the script:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(thegame)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lncurses -lm")

set(SOURCE_FILES thegame.c ./src/headers/set.h ./src/headers/functions.h ./src/headers/game.h ./src/headers/heap.h ./src/headers/lib.h
./src/headers/parser.h ./src/headers/pathfind.h ./src/headers/structures.h

./src/functions.c ./src/game.c ./src/heap.c ./src/lib.c ./src/parser.c ./src/pathfind.c ./src/set.c
)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "~/Binaries")

add_executable(thegame ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

I'm getting a lot of messages like this:

```
thegame.c:(.text.startup+0x1c): undefined reference to "mousemask"
...
```

What I'm doing Wrong?

Comment: Where is `mousemask` supposed to be defined?

Comment: it's defined in ncurses.h . but mousemask is an example. i've got a lot of undefined reference to "pow", undefined reference to "floor", etc, all defined in math.h. I think for every time I use one of that function in the project, I get an error in the log

Comment: Looks like your linker does not find its libraries. What is `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`? Its name suggests C++, but your question is C.

Comment: Oh, in the last line, I don't see where you include those flags, only `SOURCE_FILES`. (If that's the thing, I'll make this an answer).

Comment: How do I include the flags in the last line?

Comment: Honestly, I a know nothing about CMake... but my guess is that it should look something like: `add_executable(thegame ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${SOURCE_FILES})` or `add_executable(thegame ${SOURCE_FILES} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})`

Comment: nope, I get other kind of errors with this solution

Comment: But, does it find the libraries now?

Comment: No, it's the syntax of the command "add_executable..." that is not correct

Comment: Where is the `target_link_library` for ncurses?